# IIS 8.0: Problems when using parameter (query string)

Tags: iis, http-get

I have the following problem on IIS 8.0:
If I call a page with parameters e.g. http://mywebsite.com/subdir/page.html?param=1 local on the server everything is fine, but if I call the page from a client I get redirectet to the rootdir http://mywebsite.com. If I call the page without parameters, e.g. http://mywebsite.com/subdir/page.html, it's also working.

Is there a configuration to disable remote query string or something else?

Comment: Can you see if HTTP Redirect is enabled by clicking on the site in IIS and in the center pane double click HTTP Redirect. URL Rewrite rule could be another possibility.

Comment: There is no HTTP Redirect enabled.URL Rewrite Module is not installed.

Comment: What do you see in IIS logs? If IIS is doing this you should have 2 entries in the log files one with 302 response code and another with 200. How do you browse locally using localhost or the hostname ?

Comment: I use the hostname when browsing locally. 
If I do the request locally I got this entry in the IIS Log:
2016-06-07 10:34:40 W3SVC5 BMWAPTVI-FB00 172.18.75.50 GET /default2.html typ=1 80 ... 304 0 0 165 370 0

If I do it remote, this one:
2016-06-07 10:35:33 W3SVC5 BMWAPTVI-FB00 172.18.75.50 GET / - 80 - ... 200 0 0 264 305 109

Comment: For the request browsed locally I see the response status code is 304, can you try browsing in private/incognito window on the server locally ? Also can you check if there are any entries in this file C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts for the host name you are using

Comment: Also as there is no 302 IIS is not doing redirect here, it seems they got stripped over the wire. A simultaneous network trace from client and server can give us more details.

Comment: no entries in the hosts file. I'll try to do a network trace.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because of an incorrect config of a network component.